# {events} variable pair within {exp:calendar:cal} not working the same as in {exp:calendar:events}?

Tags: solspace-calendar, calendar-events

I have a scenario where I need to access conditionals that work in the {exp:calendar:events} tag, eg this works:

```
{exp:calendar:events}
    {title} {if event_never_ends}(never ends){/if}
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

but I need them to work within the {exp:calendar:cal} in order to maintain the chronological order.  I though the {events} variable pair was supposed to allow the same conditionals/variable pairs, but this doesn't work (nor does the {rules} variable pair.  Is there a special syntax or something I need to use to get something like this to work:

```
{exp:calendar:cal}
  {events}
    {event_title} {if event_never_ends}(never ends){/if}
  {/events}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of EE and Calendar are you using? Please provide exact version numbers. Have you also tried your above `{exp:calendar:cal}` code on a completely, absolutely blank EE template with nothing whatsoever on it besides the code (i.e. no CSS, JS, headers, footers, sidebars, and other 3rd-party plugins)?

Comment: EE 2.9.3 and Calendar 1.8.12.

Comment: And yes, I've tried a completely blank template - please see http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img661/9935/87MHK1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It seems `{if event_never_ends}` doesn't parse in `{exp:calendar:cal}` but does in `{exp:calendar:events}`. Although it's not sure if this is a bug or a missing feature, we'll report this to our developers.

In the meantime, a workaround could be to use an embed and pass the event_id in `{exp:calendar:cal}` into a template using `{exp:calendar:events}`, in which you can use the `{if event_never_ends}` conditional. Keep in mind that if there are many events, this would also mean many embeds, and therefore possible decreased performance. Caching might help in those cases.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, but the additional performance increase is what I'm trying to avoid.  The same goes for the {rules} variable pair - this doesn't work in {exp:calendar:cal} either.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the data out as expected using the `{events}` tag pair inside of the `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag pair either. Unfortunately, as Solspace already mentioned, I had to use an embed template and pass in the `{event_id}` to the embed and run `{exp:calendar:events}` in the embed.

I left a full example in my answer just now on my original question here. (It seems way too much info to paste in here. I will if need be though.)

[Display a single Calendar Event that spans the current date](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/34050/display-a-single-calendar-event-that-spans-the-current-date/34064#34064)