# Display a single Calendar Event that spans the current date

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar-events

I am using Calendar in an attempt to display an Event as a single entry. I have previous events and upcoming events. I need to display the "Current Event". In other words, if the event spans the dates 9-15-2015, 9-16-2015, and 9-17-2015 I need to display it if today is 9-16-2015. If there is NOT an event spanning the current date, I need to show the NEXT event in the calendar. I am using a single calendar for this site.

I want the user to be able to enter a 'range' or add rules as seperate days and times. For that reason, I have this in my date/time display:

```
{if event_has_rules}
    {rules}

    {/rules}
{/if}
{if event_recurs}
    {occurrences}
        <span style="color:#7e7f81;">{occurrence_start_date format="%l %m-%d-%Y"} &mdash; {occurrence_start_date format="%g:%i%a"} - {occurrence_end_date format="%g:%i%a"}</span></br>
    {/occurrences}
{/if}
```

I haven't quite figured the rules syntax without blowing up my template yet though...

My primary issue is with displaying the "current" event.

I have this right now:

```
{exp:calendar:events
    calendar_id="20"
    event_limit="1"
    date_range_start="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d @ %h:%i %A'}"
    show_days="-14"
    dynamic="no"
}
```

I tried the -14 in an attempt to catch anything starting 14 days before the current day.

I also tried without the date_range_start in there at all.

Answer (score 1):

With a little guidance from Solspace support, I changed to use the cal tag instead of the event tag in order to get in the date range I needed. The docs indicate being able to use the `{event}` tag pair inside, which you are, however the loop was not gathering the data as expected without providing an embed template and passing that embed template the `{event_id}`. I will attach what I ended up with below in full in hopes it may be useful to someone else.

Main template section for the event data:

```
{exp:calendar:cal
    calendar_id="20"
    date_range_start="today"
    date_range_end="today"
    pad_short_weeks="n"
}
    {display_each_day}
        {if day_event_total > 0}
            {events}
                <!-- Blog Post -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12 module_cont module_blog module_none_padding module_blog_page">
                        <div class="blog_post_page blog_post_preview has_pf">
                            <div class="preview_top">
                                <div class="preview_title">
                                    <h1 class="blogpost_title">{event_title}</h1>
                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div class="span4 module_number_9 module_cont pb50 module_iconboxes">
                                            <div class="listing_meta shortcode_iconbox">
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                                    <div class="iconbox_wrapper">
                                                        <span class="ico"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                                                        <a><h6 class="iconbox_title">When</h6></a>
                                                        <div class="iconbox_body">
                                                            {embed="_includes/_event" event_id="{event_id}"}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- .module_cont -->

                                        <div class="span4 module_number_9 module_cont pb50 module_iconboxes">
                                            <div class="listing_meta shortcode_iconbox">
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                                    <div class="iconbox_wrapper">
                                                        <span class="ico"><i class="icon-home"></i></span>
                                                        <h6 class="iconbox_title">Where</h6>
                                                        <div class="iconbox_body">
                                                            {address style="schema"}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- .module_cont -->

                                        <div class="span4 module_number_9 module_cont pb50 module_iconboxes">
                                            <img src="{address:static_map width='400' height='400' zoom='15'}" alt="{address style='inline'}" />
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- .preview_title -->
                            </div>

                            <div class="blog_post_content">
                                <article class="contentarea">{event_summary}</article>
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span12 module_number_5 module_cont pb50 module_text_area">
                                    <div class="bg_title"><h5 class="headInModule">Terms and Conditions</h5></div>
                                    <div class="module_content">
                                        <blockquote class="shortcode_blockquote left type1">
                                            <div class="blockquote_wrapper">
                                                {terms_and_conditions}
                                            </div>
                                        </blockquote>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- .module_cont -->
                            </div>



                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span12 module_number_19 module_cont pb0 module_divider"><hr></div><!-- .module_cont -->
                            </div>


                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span12 module_number_14 module_cont pb60 module_gallery photo_gallery">
                                    <div class="bg_title"><h5 class="headInModule">Gallery</h5></div>
                                    <div class="list-of-images images_in_a_row_3">
                                        {sale_images}
                                            {if image:no_images}
                                                <div class="gallery_item">
                                                    <div>There are currently no images for this sale uploaded. Please check back.</div>
                                                </div>
                                            {/if}
                                            <div class="gallery_item">
                                                <div class="gallery_item_padding">
                                                    <div class="gallery_item_wrapper">
                                                        <a href="{image:url}" class="photozoom"></a>
                                                        <img class="gallery-stand-img" src="{image:url:small}" alt="{image:title}" />
                                                        <div class="gallery_fadder"></div>
                                                        <span class="featured_items_ico"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        {/sale_images}
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- .module_cont -->
                            </div>



                            <div class="blogpost_footer">
                                <div class="blogpost_share">
                                    {exp:sharethis:button
                                        services="facebook|pinterest|twitter|googleplus"
                                        display="hcount"
                                        title="{title}"
                                        url="{current_url}"
                                    }
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--.blog_post_page -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /Blog Post -->
            {/events}
        {/if}
    {/display_each_day}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Then in the embed template:

```
{exp:calendar:events
    event_id="{embed:event_id}"
    event_limit="1"
    dynamic="no"
}
    {occurrences}
        <span style="color:#7e7f81;">{occurrence_start_date format="%l %m-%d-%Y"} &mdash; {occurrence_start_date format="%g:%i%a"} - {occurrence_end_date format="%g:%i%a"}</span></br>
    {/occurrences}
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

This achieved the data extraction I was after for the date ranges that differed.